# Obtain JS date in localtime without timezone details in date object

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I want to obtain a JS date object which returns local time but without the timezone details like "+0530 (IST)".
It should be a date object and not a string.
Is this possible in any way?

Thanks.

Comment: Date objects are always stored as UTC timestamps.

Comment: Your question is in conflict with itself, "It should be a date object and not a string", but you ask about removing part of the string representation...

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you want?

```
var d = new Date;
console.log(d); // "Thu Apr 02 2015 10:46:27 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
console.log(d.getFullYear()); // 2015
```

As you can see, date is an object. You can check sites like 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp
to see how you can get elements out of the object.